# Google cloud KMS store custom keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

Is it possible to store my AES-256 keys generated manually to google cloud kms.
I was successful on creating keys fully managed and created by Google but how to deal with keys generated before adopting google cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently support importing keys, but even if we did, we don't currently document the format of encrypted data, so we can't support interoperability with data you have encrypted yourself.

The solution to this use case is usually to use a master key in KMS which you use to wrap your AES keys, then store the wrapped keys in a data store. You can then bootstrap from the service account identities provisioned into your deployed code, using them to authorize the use of KMS to unwrap your AES keys, then use the unwrapped keys to encrypt/decrypt your data.

Answer (score 4):

Tim's answer was correct at the time, but [Cloud KMS now supports Key Import](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key).

Create an import job:

```sh
$ gcloud kms import-jobs create "my-job" \
  --location "us-central1" \
  --keyring "my-keyring" \
  --import-method "rsa-oaep-4096-sha1-aes-256" \
  --protection-level "hsm"
```

Import your key:

```sh
$ gcloud kms keys versions import \
  --import-job "my-job" \
  --location "us-central1" \
  --keyring "my-keyring" \
  --key "my-key" \
  --algorithm "<algorithm>" \
  --target-key-file ./path/to/my.key
```

Comment: Would this feature allow for the following scenarios? I can't seem to get to a YES/NO answer from the docs: 

- Encrypt on premise independently of KMS and then decrypt within GCP
- Upload the key to a different keyring as part of a restoration process and be able to decrypt the data

Comment: No, it would not.

Comment: @sethvargo about my.key file, what is format value on that file? is it an object?